# trying to get property of non-object in school.php

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm getting an Internal server error 500 when adding using laravel

in my School.php

```
    if(empty($Number[0])){ //  empty so start from 1
        $NextSchoolNumber = 1;
    }else{
        $NextSchoolNumber = ++$Number[0];
    }

    $NextSchoolCode = $City->code.$NextSchoolNumber; < this line here generates the error

    $School->schools_code = $NextSchoolCode;
```

Where $City comes from:

```
private $City; 

public function __construct(array $attributes = []) { 
    parent::__construct($attributes); 
    $this->City = new City; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the "question" you would like assistance with?

Comment: And what is the detailed error message? The 500 is the response the client gets, but on the server, the logs should contain more details on the error.

Comment: What's inside $City object could you please print_r($City) ????

Comment: private $City;

 public function __construct(array $attributes = []){
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->City = new City;
    }

this is the code for city

Comment: is `$City` an eloquent model?

Comment: Try `$City->code[NextSchoolNumber]`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki didnt work...

Comment: @RossWilson I'm not sure.. really im new to this stuff

Comment: just var_dump($City); so we can get an Idea.

Comment: show us the output of var_dump($City);

Comment: In that case can you add the code for your City class to your question?

Comment: Kindly wait.. im trying to get the php page but cant...

Comment: im sorry.. but i cant get it to show as the school.php being called from the main laravel dashboard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, thank you all,

I changed the code to

```
$NextSchoolCode = $NextSchoolNumber;
```

and it worked fine. thanks again and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array and you are use as an objects, so you are getting this types of error.

Objects data format this types

```
$data->fields
```

But array format like below, Can try this,

```
$data['fields']
```

Answer (score 0):

dd($City) and check whether code field exist or not.

Comment: The $Number doesn't exist when he check empty($Number[0]).

Comment: `empty` doesn't care if the variable exists, it will just return `true` if it doesn't exist ... nothing is trying to access 'properties' on `$Number`

Comment: not a bad idea though, especially with the lack of information :)